# Android unable to show all lmages on screen?

Tags: android, xmpp

I am  making a chat application in which I am using emoticons functionality. My emoticons are working properly but the problem is:

1. When I send only one smile, it works properly
2. I want to send more then one image in edittext or dialog, here is image snapshot:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
   builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(message1);
        if(message1.contains("x-(R"))
        {

            int len=message1.indexOf("x-(R");
            while(len!=-1)
            {
                builder.replace(len, len+4, getSmiley(1));

                message1=message1.replaceFirst("x-\\(R", "");
                len=message1.indexOf("x-(R");
            }
        }
```

For sending and showing the image, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with  getSmiley(1).toString().
it will work ?

Like 
message1=message1.replaceFirst("x-\(R", getSmiley(1).toString());

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is that you replace a string in the `builder` with `getSmiley(1)` (assume this is not empty string), then in `message1` you replace `X-R(` with empty string. `message1` and `builder` are not in sync anymore after the first replace. So when you get the `len` for second time ( `len=message1.indexOf("x-(R");` ) you replace wrong index in the `builder`.

Maybe the correct thing to do is to replace the message like the builder:

```
message1=message1.replaceFirst("x-\\(R", getSmiley(1));
```

Comment: my getsmile is a charectorsequence method..,so its giving me error. The method replaceFirst(String, String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, CharSequence)

Comment: getSmiley(1).toString() maybe? You just have to keep the length equal